# Pacemaker error and warn log showing up in syslog rather than pacemaker.log

Tags: pacemaker

I created a ping check on pacemaker, like so:

```
pcs resource create ping ocf:pacemaker:ping dampen=5s multiplier=1000 host_list=127.0.0.1 clone
```

Used something other than 127.0.0.1 of course.

Here's the source code: https://github.com/ClusterLabs/pacemaker/blob/master/extra/resources/ping

The ping check foresees an rc code of 0, 1, and any other.

Wanting to see warning and errors, I enabled debug:

```
pcs resource update ping debug=1
```

However, instead of logging to `/var/log/pacemaker.log`, these messages are logged to `/var/log/syslog`.

Articles like this are just descriptors: https://support.sciencelogic.com/s/article/3961

And this is outdated: http://www.beekhof.net/blog/2013/pacemaker-logging

There doesn't seem to be a way to set this. What am I missing?

EDIT: Most guides I'm finding on this assume CentOs.

On Ubuntu, it seems the pacemaker sysconfig it located here:`/etc/default/pacemaker`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because pacemaker inherits the corosync config in `/etc/corosync/corosync.conf` and this contains

```
to_syslog: yes
```

You could check if the pacemaker log is written to corosync.log, in this case you should have this in your corosync.conf:

```
logfile: /var/log/corosync.log
```

If you want to have a dedicated `pacemaker.log` you have to add the following configuration items to your `/etc/sysconfig/pacemaker`:

```
PCMK_logfile=/var/log/pacemaker.log
```

You can control verbosity with e.g.

```
PCMK_logpriority=warning
```

Copy the modified config file to all nodes of your cluster and reload pacemaker.

Comment: Thank you for that, I'll test this soon. I didn't know about the `to_syslog` option, a quick google says it is indeed default syslog and stderr.

There's already a `/var/log/pacemaker.log` file, I assume it will just be added to that as well, or should I make a separate one to avoid two processes overwriting each other?

Comment: No, using the existing log file should work fine.

Comment: I'm on ubuntu btw, grepped around a bit, found PCMK_logfile in `/etc/default/pacemaker`